# Story Identification : An astronomer, superconduction in the human brain, tricyclics, electron spin resonance and SETI

Tags: story-identification, astronomy

Looking for the title and author of a short story that appeared in one of
Analog's sister magazines, featuring an astronomer, Electron Spin Resonance,
tricyclics, neural superconduction and SETI.

The author mentions that the astronomer spends a great deal of time working in
a red-lit environment to optimise his photosensitivity. Naturally occurring
superconduction in the human brain, maximised by tricyclic neurotransmitters,
features strongly in this tale - along with ESR and SETI.

The astronomer designs and builds a defense system - involving lasers - to
save the planet Earth from destruction at the hands of a cosmic/Manichaean
menace.

The story was published some time during or following 1975, and was clearly
influenced by the McKenna brother's book, "The Invisible Landscape: Mind,
Hallucinogens, and the I Ching".